# Deploy Oracle Connection Issue

Tags: oracle, deployment, ssis

I have a few simply SSIS packages in VS2017 that connect to an Oracle 11g db and copy data to a few local SQL2019 db tables.

The SSIS runs fine in VS2017 when I execute it so I'm sure I have the correct oracle instant client installed. However I want to schedule the packages to run over night each working day at a set time. So I deployed the project in order to schedule them.

I have two issues preventing that. Firstly if I convert the oracle connection to a project connection the project fails to deploy every time.

While if I leave the oracle connection in the package it does deploy but running the package in SSMS "Integration Services Catalog" it fails to run with the below error.

Has anyone deployed a project with oracle connections that could assist please.

[image: error]

Comment: Please past the error directly into your question.  Nothing prevents you from doing that - either text or a screenshot.  And a lot of people here, myself included, are loathe to open links from strangers on the internet.

Comment: Oracle connections are notorius for creating all sorts of problems with SSIS. Is the development environment and the deployment target at the same server? If not, have you installed all the Oracle stuff to the target? Check, if you are running the ssis-package in 32-bit mode. If you haven't changed the 32/64 bit setting in Visual Studio, then VS uses 32 bit by default, but SQL Server defaults to 64bit (also, make sure you have the same bit-level Oracle components 32/64 installed both on development and target machines).